# How is the output of this program 12 300 in Java?

Tags: java

How come the output of this program is:

```
12
300
```

Can anyone please explain where the `300` part comes from?

Explain `calArea1()` please.

```
public class Practice3 {
    int i;
    int j;

    public static int calArea2(Practice3 t) {
        t.i=t.i+10;
        t.j=t.i+20;
        return t.i*t.j;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int area = calArea1(3,4);
        System.out.println(area);
        Practice3 t = new Practice3();
        area = calArea2(t);
        System.out.println(area);
    }

    public static int calArea1(int i, int j) {
        return i*j;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "Explain calArea1() Please", do you mean calArea2()? That's where the 300 comes from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @JiriTousek Well played haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t.i` and `t.j` start as 0.

```
t.i=t.i+10; //t.i = 0 + 10 = 10
t.j=t.i+20; // t.j = 10 + 20 = 30
return t.i*t.j; // t.i * t.j = 10 * 30 = 300
```

Comment: Thanks guys. u got it..Cameron Morrow

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake on the second line here:

```
t.i=t.i+10;
t.j=t.i+20; // << This should be t.j+20
```

Since `t.i` has been set to `10` at the time you add `20` to it, the result is `30`, which, when multiplied by `10`, gives you `300`.

Java offers a convenient operator `+=` to avoid mistakes like that:

```
t.i += 10;
t.j += 20;
```

Now the output is going to be `200`, matching the value that you expected.

Comment: First time I see someone not answer the op's question as asked but somehow still solve their problem.  I'm guessing that's what he was trying to understand.